# How to test the homomorphism law of an Applicative instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, proof, applicative, homomorphism

I'm doing the exercises from [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia); in the `Applicative` section, I write `ZipList`'s `pure` function, and check whether it follows the `Applicative` Laws.

I've checked:

- identity law
- interchange law
- composition law

But when I try to check the "homomorphism" law, I find that GHCi doesn't get the result as an `MZipList`.

I think this is because I miss to designate the `pure` to my `Applicative` type class. How can I run a `pure` function without `<*>` it to `Applicative` immediately？

Here's the `MZipList` definition and class instances:

```
newtype MZipList a = MZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
    deriving (Show)

instance Functor MZipList where
  fmap gs x = pure gs <*> x

instance Applicative MZipList where
  pure a= MZipList (repeat a)
  (MZipList gs) <*> (MZipList xs) = MZipList (zipWith ($) gs xs)
```

When I check the "Interchange" law, for example:

```
*Main> (MZipList [(*2),(*3),(*4)]) <*> pure (2)
MZipList {getZipList = [4,6,8]}
*Main> pure ($ 2) <*> (MZipList [(*2),(*3),(*4)])
MZipList {getZipList = [4,6,8]}
```

But when I check the "Homomorphism" law , the `MZipList`'s `pure` is not called:

```
*Main> pure (*2) <*> pure 2
4
*Main>  pure ((*2) 2)
4
*Main>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8):

### What is `pure`?

`pure` is simply a function to "insert" an object inside a specific `Applicative` monad. For example in:

```
test :: [Int]
test = pure 1 -- [1]
```

we are inserting `1` into the list monad, which results in the singleton `[1]`. If you have already read about the `Monad` class, then `pure` is basically the same as `return` (if you haven't don't worry).

Your instance of `Applicative` seems to be working fine.

### Your tests

When running commands in GHCi, you are basically in the `IO` monad, which is also an `Applicative`. So in general, `pure x` returns an `IO (type of x)`.

In:

```
pure (*2) <*> pure 2
```

you are "putting" `(*2)` in an `IO` object, then putting `2` in an `IO` object as well, and finally calling `<*>` as defined in the `instance Applicative IO`.

You are not testing your `MZipList` instance.

In the second example you are simply calling:

```
pure ((*2) 2)
```

If you recall, `(*2) 2` simply applies `(*2)` to `2`, thus really executing `2 * 2`. So your call is actually:

```
pure 4
```

which, in GHCi (still in the context of the `IO` monad) returns an `IO Int` object.

### How to test properly

To test the "homomorphism" law, you just need to give the compiler a small hint as to what type you really want:

So instead of:

```
pure (*2) <*> pure 2
```

you would write:

```
pure (*2) <*> (pure 2 :: MZipList Int)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/555eccf098274629)